# More of a DB than UI person but trying to Understand VS, .net, framework, core requirements for using 5.x latest

Tags: npgsql

More of a DB than UI person but trying to assist and understand VS, .net, framework, core requirements for using 5.x latest.  Where to look,  dependencies list on nuget page ?   Is there an explanation of this in more detail?

We are on version 13.1 Postgresql and still using 3.1.7 npgsql when I noticed that's more than a little behind.   Should that version (8/2016) work ok?

Comment: Why are you looking at 3.1.7 and not something newer? Is there any reason you can't use Npgsql 5.0?

Comment: My question was where do I look for .net, framework, core requirements for 5.x.  We've figured out that we can use 5.0.4 for our UI and Loading Service.  I've already implemented it ... and will start my questions about it in another thread.